# xrandr equivalent for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, video, display, xrandr, scaling

My old 7" Eee netbook runs Linux. I'm able to run the following command to scale what the display shows from the native/tiny 800x480 to something a little larger:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1.28x1.28
```

Now I have a newer 10" netbook running Windows 7 (starter). Native resolution is 1024x600 and I'm looking for something like xrandr for Windows to try and scale *it* up a bit, like I did the old Eee.

Darned if I can find any Windows options though. Are there any?

If it matters, the Video adapter is Intel GMA 3150. The netbook itself is a Toshiba NB255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the Asus drivers? I seem to recall there's an Asus utility that would allow you to change the scale, it may just be having the correct video driver.

*Edit* I don't see anything for the Toshiba, but you could try a virtual screen extender such as [gimespace](http://sites.google.com/site/gimespace/) or you can try forcing "pan and scan" functionality by using an XP driver as mentioned [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/w7itprogeneral/thread/1e9bac2b-681d-4c78-bdda-e74fa0ce2ea4)

> Just to let you know, I've tried the above with an Asus EeePC 1001PX-BLK033S, AND IT WORKS.
>
> This netbook has an Intel GMA 3150 graphics card and came preinstalled with Windows 7 Starter.
>
> The intel GMA driver for Windows 7 version 8.14.10.1929 [23/09/2009] did not allow me to set up pan-and-scan. The "Hide modes that this monitor cannot display" checkbox was grayed out. I could set screen resolutions larger than the native 1024x600 (e.g. 1024x768) but these were scaled down to fit on the screen - no panning.
>
> This is what I did to get it working:
>
> -Download the Intel GMA 3150 driver for Windows XP (latest version is 6.14.10.5260 [25/04/2010] as of this writing) from the Intel driver support site.
>
> -Uninstall the Intel GMA driver for Windows 7 via add-remove programs, then remove the video cards from the device manager as well.
>
> -Reboot.
>
> -Unzip and install the Windows XP driver (activating Windows XP Service Pack 3 compatibility mode and administrator rights for Setup.exe).
>
> -Reboot.
>
> -Windows will detect the video card and try to install a driver for it. The version 8.xx driver seems to be still in there somewhere (I think it comes with Windows 7), and since it's a newer version, Windows 7 will choose it over the version 6.xx, which is the one we want. So wait until it's done installing version 8.xx, then open the device manager and update the video card driver. When prompted, choose to find a driver manually, then to choose a driver from a list. You should see both versions 6.xx and 8.xx in there, choose the 6.xx and click Next. Finish the update. If you don't see both versions 6.xx and 8.xx, reboot and try again.
>
> -Reboot. With any luck the video card should now be using the Windows XP driver (version 6.xx). Then, that "Hide modes that this monitor cannot display" checkbox should be enabled, allowing you to uncheck it.
>
> - Follow step H from the above post by Daniel_L to enable pan-and-scan.
>
> At this point I have two "Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator 3150" video cards showing up in the device manager. Both are using the XP driver (version 6.xx). I believe one of them drives the internal LCD and the other the external VGA but I'm not sure.
>
> I'm posting this from a 1280x1024 pan-and-scan desktop :)

Comment: My apologies, I never mentioned that the new netbook is a Toshiba NB255! No asus drivers for me. :-\  You're right though, the old Eee's came with some Asus utilities that did this, IIRC.

Comment: No problem, I found some instructions that, while they were for an EEPC, apply to the same graphics adapter.

Comment: Nice find! I'll give those a shot, that looks like just the ticket.

Comment: Panning & scanning now. Thanks for the good find!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped!